# Receber um Model por parâmetro numa função

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou a tentar receber um `Model` numa função, que passo de uma `view` (apesar de não saber se é possível) para depois poder gerar uma lista e gerar um PDF.

A minha `View`:

```
    @model List<BDOleoTorres.Models.AutoDeclaracoesCertISCC>
    Clique <a href="@Url.Action("downloadListaISCC", "Alertas", new { modelISCC = Model })">aqui</a> para gerar lista para PDF
```

O meu `controller`:

```
public ActionResult downloadListaISCC(List<AutoDeclaracoesCertISCC> modelISCC)
{
    //Código para gerar PDF com o modelISCC recebido
    return PartialView("AlertaCertOUAPartial");
}
```

Eu recebo o `modelISCC` sempre a sem dados e não sei se o que estou a tentar fazer é possível, se não for vou tentar arranjar outra solução.

Comment: Acho que você deveria apenas guardar o identificador do objeto e não todo o objeto, seria algo bem mais "bonito". E no `downloadListaISCC` consultar o objeto para gerar o `PDF`.

Comment: Como é que guardo apenas o identificador do objecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei por arranjar uma solução que talvez não sendo a mais eficaz está trabalhando bem.
O que estou a fazer é: Chamo um função javascript; Vou buscar o valor dos Filtros; Chamo a função (controller) para gerar o PDF, enviando os dados dos filtros; Calculo de novo a lista e gero o PDF.

Ou seja:
View:

```
Clique <a onclick="downloadListaAlertasISCC()" style="cursor:pointer">aqui</a> para gerar lista para PDF
```

Função `downloadListaAlertasISCC` no `Javascript`:

```
function downloadListaAlertasISCC() {
   var dataFiltro = $("#FiltrarListContrato").val();
   //Outros filtros
   window.location.href = "/Alertas/downloadListaISCC?idForn=" + dataFiltro + "";
```

}

Controller:

```
public ActionResult downloadListaISCC(DateTime? DataFimFiltro)

    //Calculo o resultado do filtros (lista)
    //Gerar a lista para PDF
    //Retornar ficheiro PDF gerado
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O que entendo por receber um `Model` em uma `Action` é você ter a representação de cada propriedade desse `Model` ma view e quando a requisição à `Action` é feita o *framework* do *ASP.NET MVC* vai efetuar o *parser* dos campos para uma instância do `Model`.

Como vocês já comentaram, criar cada campo que se deseja trafegar de cada item da lista na `view` para então poder receber um `List<Model>` fácil de manipular na `Action` é algo penoso para o ambiente. Principalmente se você não tem como prever o tamanho que suas listas podem alcançar.

Se sua lista recebe valores digitados pelo usuário e por isso você precisa postar todo o `Model`, então imaginando como em uma tela de pedido em qua cada produto é preenchido pelo usuário, talvez postar item a item seja meno doloroso.

Se não é isso, se você apenas passa a lista para a `View` e depois só precisar saber quais foram os itens dessa lista quando ela for postada para a `Action`, então você realmente pode resolver isso de outra forma, com uma lista de Id´s.

Você na hora de montar a view pode criar algo do tipo:

```razor
@model List<BDOleoTorres.Models.AutoDeclaracoesCertISCC>
...
@foreach (var I=0; I<Model.Count(); I++)
{
    <input type="hidden" id="modelId_@I" name="modelId[@I]" />
}
@* Outros campos de forma que não precisam ser postados *@
....
```

Na sua `Action` você recebe assim:

```c-sharp
public ActionResult downloadListaISCC(int[] modelId)
{
    // recupera sua lista do banco de dados 
    // processa a lista
}
```

Dessa forma, com certeza você estará economizando recursos.

Se essa lista for sobre exclusões e adições na `View` e então dependerá do que o usuário for fazer, então não dará certo tentar definir o índice dos campos para renderizar, mas sim setar os índices antes de postar.

Exemplo:

```razor
@model List<BDOleoTorres.Models.AutoDeclaracoesCertISCC>
...
@foreach (var I=0; I<Model.Count(); I++)
{
    <input type="hidden" id="modelId" name="modelId" />
}
@* Outros campos de forma que não precisam ser postados *@
....
```

Antes de postar, você faria algo como:

```javascript
$("#seuForm").submit(function () {
    var idx = 0;
    $("#modelId", this).each(function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        $self.attr("id", $self.attr("id") + "_" + idx);
        $self.attr("name", $self.attr("name") + "[" + idx + "]");
        idx++;
    });
});
```

Isso é necessário porque se houver um corte na sequência de índices sua lista não será passada para o `Model` na `Action` completamente.

Seguindo essa idéia, você pode adicionar até mais de um campo, para cada um deles você cria um parâmetro como vetor na `Action`, ou pode optar por um `ModelView`, assim ficaria mais "elegante".

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seja mais interessante salvar a lista de identificadores.

Algo assim:

```
@model List<long>
    Clique <a href="@Url.Action("downloadListaISCC", "Alertas", new { ids = Model })">aqui</a> para gerar lista para PDF
```

E no controller assim:

```
public ActionResult downloadListaISCC(long[] ids)
{
    // Buscar no banco de dados pelo identificador
    //Código para gerar PDF com o modelISCC recebido
    return PartialView("AlertaCertOUAPartial");
}
```

**Obs: não testei, qualquer problema comenta.**

Edit:

Dê uma olhada [nessa](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) referência, acho que vai te ajudar.

Comment: o problema é que tenho uma `List` e não apenas um elemento, logo essa solução não vai funcionar

Comment: Existe filtro para carregar essa lista?

Comment: Sim existe. Tenho mesmo de enviar o Model que estou a receber na view

Comment: Então você tem que salvar, somente o que for necessário para recuperar a lista, por que serializar uma lista gigantesca no cliente pode custar caro.

Comment: Editei minha resposta, mais acho que seu problema é com a lista, acho nem vai funcionar assim.

Comment: Pois, assim não vai dar porque preciso mesmo daquele tipo de dados (`AutoDeclaracoesCertISCC`) porque estou a imprimir uma lista. O que posso tentar fazer é enviar os id's numa lista por uma viewbag

Comment: Talvez você tenha que usar um tipo de lista mais primitivo como `ICollection` ou `[]`, em um caso aqui uso `[]` para uma lista de ids (`long[] ids`), mais a requisição é feita por Ajax, passando um objeto(array) `JSON`.

Comment: Acabei por ir por Javascript. Envio a partir do js os filtros, depois no controller calculo de novo a lista (com o resultado dos filtros) e de seguida gero o PDF. Talvez não seja a maneira mais optimizada, pois estou a calcular duas vezes a mesma lista, mas paciência, vai ficar assim. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Só sei que não é uma boa prática guardar grande quantidade de informações no cliente(browser) ou em session(memória servidor), no caso do `MVC` que veio para corrigir o bom e pesado `WebForms`. E se puder postar sua solução para os outros usuários que tiverem o mesmo problema.